# Treating Missing Cells in Anova

Tags: anova, missing-data

I am analyzing data which has a row for each observation of a range of species. Other data in each row (covariates/parameters) include the sample point ID, date and time observed, total survey lenghth (in days) for that entire sample point (range = 5-38 days), phase (before/during/after treatment) and zone (control, on-trail, and off-trail). Observations are made by 315 different sample points, somewhat evenly distributed between the three zones and phases.

I want to run an ANOVA to compare the detection rate of each species, with detection rate being equal to the number of detections per sample point day for each of the nine phase/zone combinations. I.E. if there are 100 deer observed in the before/control combination, and 20 sample points collected these observations over a total of 100 days, the detection rate of deer for the before/control data set would be 100/(20*100) = 0.05 deer per sample point day.

I can easily get this detection rate for each species, but in order to run an ANOVA on the average number of observations by effort for each species observed I need all of the values, including the days where no species was observed. I think this means I have a lot of missing "0" cells in my data.

I'm looking for suggestions on how to treat the missing cells when applying ANOVA. Or perhaps a different way to consider this problem which would not result in a loss of statistical power. Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Welcome! Currently the question is very close to an Excel operation question and will likely be flagged as off-topic and closed or moved. Perhaps you can revise it to focus on how to treat the cells with missing data when applying ANOVA? That may make it fit for this board.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Penguin Knight. I've reframed the question.